# Upload Destination

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

I've been building a small blog with the python micro-framework flask and I want to be able to upload photos for blogposts. I found the [flask-uploads](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Uploads/) package, which makes it very convenient to incorporate upload to an application. I then found the source on bitbucket along with [an example](https://bitbucket.org/leafstorm/flask-uploads/src/440e06b851d2/example/photolog.py).

The example puts uploaded photos into /tmp/photolog, but I wanted a more permanent location for my uploads, so I chose to use a folder within my application folder, but that caused an OSERROR 13 (permission error). Further reading suggested that I might need to update the permissions for the folder I want to use for uploads, but I'm not sure exactly how I should configure the permissions to make this work.

I read a little bit about flask 0.8's instance folder which should be used for uploads, but simply trying to upload to a folder named instance within my application directory doesn't seem to make a difference (which is to be expected).

This seems to be a very simple problem and I've found flask to be a very easy-to-use framework, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I'm sure I'm completely misunderstanding how the instance folder is supposed to be used, but I'm struggling to find examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to make sure that the user or group that your server runs as has write access to the directory where you want to upload those files.